# Получение даты рождения на java

Tags: java, дата

Как получить день рождения человека, зная дату рождения человека.

Например день рождения у него 12.03.1986, а нужно получить дату рождения 12.03.2016.

Добавил к задаче:

Вывести именно ту дату, когда ему исполнилось 18 лет.

Comment: Непонятно, что именно вам нужно. Предположу: день недели в этом году, на который приходиться день рождения?

Comment: день рождения у него 12.03.1986, а нужно сделать return 12.03.2016. год нынешний.

Comment: Вообще-то наоборот, дата рождения - это конкретный день конкретного года, когда человек появился на свет, а день рождения - он только раз в году.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте Calendar

```
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.setTime(dr); // Дата рождения
c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);          // год который вам нужен

System.out.println(c2.getTime());     // результат
```

---

для того что бы добавить 18 лет

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dr); // Дата рождения
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 18);    // добавляем 18 лет

System.out.println(c.getTime());     // результат
```

Comment: А что будет с 29 декабря?
2016 високосный - я понял вашу шутку.

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov ничего не будет. вот с 29 февраля нужно будет учесть. Этот код даст 1 марта, как я знаю

Comment: а если немного изменить задачу. Вывести именно ту дату, когда ему исполнилось 18 лет

Answer (score 3):

В Java 8 можно сделать так:

```
LocalDate birthDay = LocalDate.of(1986, 3, 12);
LocalDate birthDay18 = birthDay.plusYears(18);
LocalDate birthDay2016 = birthDay.withYear(2016);
```

Answer (score 1):

Существует довольно простой алгоритм вычисления дня недели для любой даты григорианского календаря позднее 1583 года. Григорианский календарь начал действовать в 1582 — после 4 октября сразу настало 15 октября.

Положим год — год, месяц — номер месяца, день — день, тогда

a = (14 − месяц) / 12
y = год − a
m = месяц + 12 * a − 2
ДеньНедели = (7000 + (день + y + y / 4 − y / 100 + y / 400 + (31 * m) / 12)) ОСТАТОК 7
Все деления целочисленные (остаток отбрасывается).

Результат: 0 — воскресенье, 1 — понедельник и т. д.

ссылка на оригинал [алгоритма вычисления дня недели, по дате](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C)

Comment: Не совсем понятно как день недели связан с вопросом?

Comment: @Batanichek какой вопрос, такой и ответ(

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вот так:

```
String happy = "12.03"
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
int month=c.get(c.MONTH)+1;
int day=c.get(c.DAY_OF_MONTH);
String date = (day+"."+month);

if (happy == date)
System.out.println ("С днем Рождения");
```